# less-like pager with filter feature?

Tags: plain-text

I'd like to have a pager program, similar to `less`, with the following added commands:

- Prompt for a regular expression and display only lines that match it;
- Prompt for a regular expression and remove from the current display lines that match it; and
- Revert to showing the entire file.
- Show the current filters.

Another nice feature would be an optional visual indication that lines have been hidden.

Filtering the input to `less, as in:

```
grep pattern filename | less
```

is only a *partial* solution. It's missing the ability to easily reconfigure the filtering without exiting and restarting the pager.

I'm looking for something that works in text mode, though a GUI tool would also be helpful.

I've taken a quick look at the `most` pager, and it doesn't seem to have such a feature.

Ideally I'd like to see this as a new feature in a future release in `less`. I might contact the maintainer with a suggestion. Meanwhile, does such a thing already exist?

Comment: There's a new tool called `slit` https://github.com/tigrawap/slit that looks close to what I was asking about. I haven't tried it yet. The build instructions are only for MacOS.

Comment: The  [discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/6692i7/slit_a_modern_pager_for_viewing_logs/) mentions another tool called
[Logfile Navigator](http://lnav.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this is a little embarrassing.

I suggested this feature to Mark Nudelman, the maintainer of the `less` command. His response:

> Is there something in this request that isn't already handled
>   by the & command?

I've somehow managed to use `less` for several decades without noticing that that command exists.

Here's the documentation:

> &pattern
>
> Display  only lines which match the pattern; lines which do
>   not match the pattern are not displayed.  If *pattern* is empty
>   (if you type `&` immediately followed by ENTER), any filtering is
>   turned off, and all lines are displayed.  While filtering is
>   in effect, an ampersand is displayed at the beginning of the
>   prompt, as a reminder that some lines in the file may be hidden.
>
> Certain characters are special as in the `/` command:
>
> ^N or !
>       Display only lines which do NOT match the pattern.
>
> ^R
>       Don't interpret regular expression metacharacters; that is, do a simple textual comparison.